# How do I figure out why MVC5 attribute routing isn't being added to the routing table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some attribute routes that are not being added to the routing tables for some reason.

I found this [ASP MVC 5 Attribute routing not registering routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727305/asp-mvc-5-attribute-routing-not-registering-routes)

but that wasn't the solution in my case. Is there a way to find out why a route isn't being added?

thanks,

john

Comment: Use Glimpse: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse#route. See here too: http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Routes-Tab

Comment: My problem is occurring during the time that routes are added to the route table, for some reason some routes are not being added. I think this will just show me the status of the route table, correct?

Comment: Yes, can you post your code?

Comment: What is odd is that some routes work while others do not. I'll work on stripping the app down to a basic point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `MapAttributeRoutes`?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{    
    // See http://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki for more options.
    // To debug routes locally using the built in ASP.NET development server, go to /routes.axd

    routes.MapAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Comment: Some routes work while others don't. I'm calling   `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`